# Different way to implement this threading?

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying out threads in python. I want a spinning cursor to display while another method runs (for 5-10 mins). I've done out some code but am wondering is this how you would do it? i don't like to use globals, so I assume there is a better way?

```
c = True 

def b():
    for j in itertools.cycle('/-\|'):
        if (c == True):
            sys.stdout.write(j)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            sys.stdout.write('\b')
        else:
            return

def a():
    global c
    #code does stuff here for 5-10 minutes
    #simulate with sleep
    time.sleep(2)
    c = False

Thread(target = a).start()
Thread(target = b).start()
```

EDIT:

Another issue now is that when the processing ends the last element of the spinning cursor is still on screen. so something like `\` is printed.

Comment: on a sidenote: use `if c` instead of `if (c == True)`

Comment: @jamylak Is there any difference under the hood, I always thought they were the same thing?

Comment: There is a difference, `if c` will evaluate true if you have `c = 'abc'` or `c = [1, 2, 3]` but not `c = ''` or `c = {}` etc. However it is better style to just use `if x`

Comment: you can run `a()` function in the main thread if there is no other code. Heartbeat thread `b` should be daemon (it should exit if there are no non-daemonic threads left). You could print space `" \b"` to overwrite `"\\"`

Answer (score 3):

You could use events:
http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

I tested this and it works. It also keeps everything in sync. You should avoid changing/reading the same variables in different threads without synchronizing them.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from threading import Thread
from threading import Event
import time
import itertools
import sys

def b(event):
    for j in itertools.cycle('/-\|'):
        if not event.is_set():
            sys.stdout.write(j)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            time.sleep(0.1)
            sys.stdout.write('\b')
        else:
            return

def a(event):
    #code does stuff here for 5-10 minutes
    #simulate with sleep
    time.sleep(2)
    event.set()

def main():
    c = Event()
    Thread(target = a, kwargs = {'event': c}).start()
    Thread(target = b, kwargs = {'event': c}).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Related to 'kwargs', from Python docs (URL in the beginning of the post):

```
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={})
...
    kwargs is a dictionary of keyword arguments for the target invocation. Defaults to {}.
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like a much better way. Is `kwargs = {'event': c}` just the syntax of passing in the event c? What is kwargs?

Comment: 'kwargs' is a dictionary that you can use to pass arguments further to your thread's implementing function.

Comment: Thanks Mihai. does it have to be called kwargs? I cant see any documentation on that. Why cant I just pass in c? To add another parameter I then have to do this? `kwargs = {'xpto': 123, 'event': c }`? i tried to add one and then have kwargs after it, but that did not work, so I stuck it inside.

Comment: @Paul: Yes. You should send arguments to your functions using `kwargs` dict.

Comment: Using `kwargs = {'event': c}` here is not necessary. In fact it's a little confusing since `a()` and `b()` don't define any keyword arguments. Replacing them with a simpler `args = (c,)` which is consistent would be better. Given that, it might more readable if you renamed `c` to `event` and then used `args = (event,)` to construct the two `Thread`s.

Comment: you could use `event.wait(0.1)` instead of `time.sleep(0.1)`. The former should return sooner after `event.set()`. Though it doesn't matter for the small timeout and it consumes CPU (it might matter for battery-powered notebook if the timeout is large). If you don't use `.wait()` then a simple flag would do as well.

Answer (score 3):

You're on the right track mostly, except for the global variable. Normally you'd needed to coordinate access to shared data like that with a lock or semaphore, but in this special case you can take a short-cut and just use whether one of the threads is running or not instead. This is what I mean:

```
from threading import Thread
from threading import Event
import time
import itertools
import sys

def monitor_thread(watched_thread):
    chars = itertools.cycle('/-\|')
    while watched_thread.is_alive():
        sys.stdout.write(chars.next())
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.stdout.write('\b')

def worker_thread():
    # code does stuff here - simulated with sleep
    time.sleep(2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    watched_thread = Thread(target=worker_thread)
    watched_thread.start()
    Thread(target=monitor_thread, args=(watched_thread,)).start()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not properly synchronized. But I will not try to explain it all to you right now because it's a whole lot of knowledge. Try to read this: http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm

But in your case it's not that bad that things aren't synchronized correctyl. The only thing that could happen, is that the spining bar spins a few ms longer than the background task actually needs.

Comment: Thanks, while I know I don't need to synchronize here it is good to read about he different things available to me in python.